# Date is not getting properly formatted in Java

Tags: java, datetime, date-formatting, date

I am trying to format a date of the format "yyyy-MM-dd" to "dd MM, yyyy" but for some dates I get incorrect year.

Here is my code:

```
DateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
DateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM, yyyy");
Date date = originalFormat.parse(dob);
dob = targetFormat.format(date);
```

INPUT: 27-05-1999
OUTPUT: 19 October, 0032

As you can see the input date is different that the output date. I cannot understand how to get this right.

Comment: Your input pattern seems to be "dd-MM-yyyy"

Comment: I'm confused why you thought the year was first in the input

Comment: You haven’t switched over to the newer Java date and time classes yet? What’s holding you back? I recommend them. I even think they would give you an exception message with a hint of what was wrong with your attempt (always a good thing).

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern is wrong. You input `27-05-1999`, so the correct date format is `dd-MM-yyyy`:

```
String dob = "27-05-1999";
DateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
DateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM, yyyy");
Date date = originalFormat.parse(dob);
dob = targetFormat.format(date);

System.out.println(dob);
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/kwYnXr)

Answer (score 0):

Your input is: 27-05-1999 and your dateFormat is: yyyy-MM-dd. You are actually using wrong format of date.

This code will work properly.

```
String dob = "27-05-1999";
DateFormat sourceFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
DateFormat destFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM, yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
Date date = sourceFormat.parse(dob);
dob = destFormat.format(date);
System.out.println(dob);  // output : 27 May, 1999
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    DateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
    DateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM, yyyy");
    Date date = originalFormat.parse("1999-05-27");
    String dob = targetFormat.format(date);

    System.out.println(dob);
```

> Look at the input format you were entering the wrong format.

if you wish to keep the same input format, then use the following code

```
    DateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    DateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM, yyyy");
    Date date = originalFormat.parse("27-05-1999");
    String dob = targetFormat.format(date);

    System.out.println(dob);
```

> OUTPUT in both the cases

27 05, 1999

Answer (score 0):

the following code should give you some idea what is the problem here,

the problem is in the expression here,

```
//String dob = "1999-05-27";
//DateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);

String dob = "27-05-1999";
DateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);

DateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM, yyyy");
Date date = originalFormat.parse(dob);
dob = targetFormat.format(date);
System.out.println(dob);
```

You could also check out the detailed expressions information on the java docs, following url should help you with that:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html